# TCP Client - Data gets corrupted only in some parts

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I have a client application that sends file to server. The problem is that in client part the file is read correctly, I can save byte array again after I read it and it saves as a valid jpg. On the server end however, the data gets corrupted in some places. All I do is keep adding to the List all incoming data until client closes connection.

I overlapped both client and server data sent/received and as you can see there are places where data doesn't match: http://s16.postimage.org/mtmm1hssl/corrupted_data.png

I don't understand how is this possible, I'm using a big buffer and the image is fairly small, so even when image is received by the server in one 'chunk', the data is still corrupted.

Any ideas why this is happening?

**UPDATE:**

**CLIENT Side:**

I'm fetching an image with HttpWebRequest:

```
                  List<byte> test_buffer = new List<byte>();

                  using (Stream MyResponseStream = hwresponse.GetResponseStream())
                  {
                      byte[] MyBuffer = new byte[4096];
                      int BytesRead;

                      while (0 < (BytesRead = MyResponseStream.Read(MyBuffer, 0, MyBuffer.Length)))
                      {

                          for (int i = 0; i < BytesRead; i++)
                          {
                              test_buffer.Add(MyBuffer[i]); // just for testing
                          }

                          TCP_R.SendBytes(MyBuffer); // send data back to server
                      }
                  }

                  TCP_R.Close(); // tell server that we're done sending data
```

TCP_R is a class that handles all the TCP stuff (connect to server/send data)

This is the TCP_R.SendBytes function:

```
    public void SendBytes(Byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            if (m_clientSocket != null)
            {
                m_clientSocket.Send(data);
            }

        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            log("send_bytes err: " + se.Message);
        }
    }
```

Notice I used *test_buffer* to collect all the bytes to verify if everything is received correctly. If I use this code:

```
                  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(test_buffer.ToArray());
                  Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
                  returnImage.Save("image.jpg");
```

The image is created successfully. So I assume client sends out data correctly.

**SERVER Side:**

I collect the data using OnDataReceived function and build all the data in REQUEST_RESPONSE which is `List<byte>`:

```
  public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {

        try
        {
            SocketPacket socketData = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState; // cast

            int iRx = 0;

                iRx = socketData.m_currentSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
                char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];

                System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder(); // CAN THIS BE CAUSING THE PROBLEM!?!
                int charLen = d.GetChars(socketData.dataBuffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);


                for (int s = 0; s < charLen; s++)
                {

                    RESPONSE_DATA.Add(socketData.dataBuffer[s]); // Collect response data

                }

                WaitForData(socketData.m_currentSocket, socketData.socket_id, REQUEST_INDEX_ID);

            }

        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {

        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {

        }
    }
```

**UPDATE2:**
It appears that these lines are causing the problem:

```
                System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder(); // CAN THIS BE CAUSING THE PROBLEM!?!
                int charLen = d.GetChars(socketData.dataBuffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
```

How can I fetch the data into socketData.dataBuffer without using Decoder?

**SOLUTION:**
Even though I was reading directly from dataBuffer, the 'd.GetChars(socketData.dataBuffer..' line somehow screwed up the buffer and therefor I got screwed up data. I still needed to use GetChars too to read first part of packet as string so I simply changed:

```
 int charLen = d.GetChars(socketData.dataBuffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
```

to:

```
 byte[] tmp_a = new byte[socketData.dataBuffer.Length];
 tmp_a = socketData.dataBuffer;
 int charLen = d.GetChars(tmp_a, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
```

And now everything works smoothly. Apparently somehow calling getChars directly on buffer affected the buffer.

Comment: Show us some code. You cannot expect us to answer this question if you leave out all the details.

Comment: I suspect something is wrong in your code, either on the client or the server. Unfortunately you haven't shown us either the client or the server code, which makes it hard to tell...

Comment: Need to see your code... both the sending and the receiving.

Comment: We need to see the code doing the receiving, in particular the Read/Receive loop, and how it handles the return value of Read/Receive, and where it is handling counts/offsets. If none of this sounds familiar, then it is *definitely* the problem.

Comment: @user1192403 re your "how can I?" question: that is what Receive does. GetChars is reading **out of** the buffer

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an encoding problem.

The key concept here is that encoding is for text, and images are not text.

Do not try to encode or decode the bytes before sending or after receiving.

Similarly, if you read or write the image from or to a file, do not try to encode or decode, use a binary mode.

Just don't try to convert the bytes to chars, there is no meaningful way to do so.

Comment: That is pure speculation. In particular, sending binary data raw over tcp shouldn't involve any encoding.

Comment: The question doesn't lend itself to much other than speculation.

Comment: And yes, it shouldn't involve any encoding, which is why I thought encoding might be the problem.

Comment: Samuel, I think you're right. Can you please check my server side code, I got UTF8 in there, how can I fetch all the bytes in buffer without using the UTF8 encoding!?

Comment: @user1192403 why on earth are you using text handling at all? Jpg is not text data. You should be using just raw byte[] for this. No "char" at all.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I found this code example on ms site. How can I read the incoming data in byte[] array? Can you please show me an example?

Comment: @Samuel then I applaud your guess - but there are a number of ways of messing up stream handling (most commonly not handling the return from Read/Receive correctly). Good job, though.

Comment: @Samuel that example is obviously text-oriented. The byte[] here is socketData.dataBuffer - just copy iRx bytes out until iRx <= 0

Comment: @MarcGravell I did as you sad and changed loop condition to s<iRx, but I get the same result. I'm accessing socketData.dataBuffer directly when I populate the byte list and dataBuffer is byte array, I don't see why it still screws up!? onRecieve I call 'getChars(socketData.dataBuffer' can this affect dataBuffer somehow?! Thanks!

Comment: @user1192403 and what is RESPONSE_DATA?

Comment: RESPONSE_DATA is List<byte>. I got it working, for some reason when calling getchars on dataBuffer. The buffer gets screwed up, modifed by getchars, at least that's what it seams. Thanks for your help!